# How to get running processes info of remote machine

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, network-programming

I want to know how to get running process or tasks of remote PC in VC++.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384724%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways. One is to open that machine's registry, and enumerate processes via the registry interface to the performance data.

Another would be to connect to that the WMI namespace on that machine, and then enumerate the instances of `Win32_Process`.